# How can I find the invisible table in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

There is a table named `IM_RESULT_INFO`. Because I can see it by `SELECT * FROM IM_RESULT_INFO`.

But it doesn't exist in table nor view lists in sqldeveloper. I also tested `SELECT * FROM all_all_tables` and `SELECT * FROM dba_tables`, and couldn't find the table.

In Eclipse IDE, I searched for it in whole project files, but the only code I found was `SELECT ... FROM IM_RESULT_INFO`.

I think it is a mixture of tables, but there's no way to analyze it. How can I find it?

Comment: Might be a view, or a synonym or materialized view. Check `all_synonyms` or `all_views` or `all_mviews` data dictionary view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It must be a synonym or a view, check the synonyms view to see what object is referenced by it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM all_synonyms 
WHERE synonym_name = 'IM_RESULT_INFO'
```

Or the views view:

```
SELECT * 
FROM all_views 
WHERE view_name = 'IM_RESULT_INFO'
```

Comment: It could even be a view

Comment: @pablomatico I could find it just by your code. I also learned about synonym at first time.

Answer (score 7):

You can check in ALL_OBJECTS if you are not sure about the type of an object. It will provide you the Types and other important details also.
For Materialized view please check ALL_MVIEWS.

```
SELECT *
FROM   ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE  OBJECT_NAME='IM_RESULT_INFO';
```

Comment: It gives me more information. I think I'll use the syntax a lot.